# Web API throws "The number of provided parameters is wrong" for valid Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've a Web API Controller which has following method in it;

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("testing")]
public Token Testing(string username, string password, string companyName, string groupName, bool acceptedTerms)
```

This is working locally on my VS 2015 and not working on the Remote IIS (Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5).

The error I'm getting is;

```
The number of provided parameters for method 'Company.API.Controllers.UserController.Testing' is wrong.
Parameter name: parameters
```

The URL which throws this error has all the required parameters;
http://host/testing?username=user@gmail.com&password=qwertyui&companyName=XYZ&groupName=ABC&acceptedTerms=true

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `@` sign to `&#64;`?

Comment: @cramopy I tried without the `@` sign and still the same result

Comment: I think you need to use [FromUri] attribute before your action parameters

Comment: The error point to UserController.Login, but you posted code for Testing method? Are they identical?

Comment: @jpgrassi yes, they are identical. I've updated the question.

Comment: can you try change `HttpPost` attribute to `HttpGet`?

Comment: @vahid already tried that with no success

Comment: @Grundy I will try it after 5 hours or so, but that's not useful as we already have a mobile app working with this Web service

Comment: what happens when you deploy this on your local IIS (not VS) with release profile?

Comment: @Nirman Same result on my IIS v10 running on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by setting `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to `True` for the `Application Pool`; but I'm still not sure why this happens. Any more information on this is highly appreciated.